# OAI Jaxen XPath problem

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm having big problems with Xpath evaluation using Jaxen.

Here's part of XML i'm evaluating on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd">
  <responseDate>2011-05-31T13:04:08+00:00</responseDate>
  <request metadataPrefix="oai_dc" verb="ListRecords">http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/oai2</request>
  <ListRecords>
    <record>
      <header>
        <identifier>oai:CiteSeerXPSU:10.1.1.1.1484</identifier>
        <datestamp>2009-05-24</datestamp>
      </header>
      <metadata>
        <oai_dc:dc xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">
          <dc:title>Winner-Take-All..</dc:title>
          <dc:relation>10.1.1.134.6077</dc:relation>
          <dc:relation>10.1.1.65.2144</dc:relation>
          <dc:relation>10.1.1.54.7277</dc:relation>
          <dc:relation>10.1.1.48.5282</dc:relation>
        </oai_dc:dc>
      </metadata>
    </record>
    <resumptionToken>10.1.1.1.2041-1547151-500-oai_dc</resumptionToken>
  </ListRecords>
</OAI-PMH>
```

I'm using Jaxen because in my use case it's much faster then Apache implementation. I'm using W3C DOM for XML representation.

I need to select all record arguments, and then on selected nodes evaluate other xpaths (it's needed because of my processing architecture).

I'm selecting all record nodes (this works):

```
/OAI-PMH/ListRecords/record
```

Then on every selected record node I'm evaluating other xpaths to get needed data:

Select identifier text value (this works):

```
header/identifier/text()
```

Select title text value (this does NOT work):

```
metadata/oai_dc:dc/dc:title/text()
```

I've registered namespaces prefixes with their URIs (oai_dc and dc). I also tried other xpaths but none of them work:

```
metadata/dc/title/text()
metadata//dc:title/text()
```

I've read other stackoverflow questions about xpaths, namespaces and solution to add prefix "oai" with URI "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/". I tried adding that "oai:" prefix to nodes without defined prefix but as result I even didn't select record nodes. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Solution:**
Problem was about parser (thanks jasso). It wasn't set to be namespace aware - after changing that setting everything works fine, as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see how the XPath expression `/OAI-PMH/ListRecords/record` can possibly select anything, since your document does not have a `{}OAI-PMH` element, only a `{http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}OAI-PMH` element. See http://jaxen.codehaus.org/faq.html

Comment: I know, and that's weird for me too. I've already read Jaxen FAQ - doesn't help me

Comment: I can't actually disagree with Dr. Kay but `/OAI-PMH/ListRecords/record` could select something if the parser was not set to be namespace aware and therefore document object didn't have any namespace nodes. Then again, in that case this would actually be a parser issue, not an XPath issue. So the point being: @Daimon, show us the code; how you parse the XML, how you register namespaces and how you execute the XPath expressions.

Comment: Thanks jasso! The issue was about parsing - parser wasn't set to be namespace aware.

Comment: @Daimon, it sounds like you didn't understand @Michael's answer. `{}OAI-PMH` means an element named `OAI-PMH` in **no namespace**.

Comment: Thansk jasso. You're right: although XPath is very strict that an unprefixed name will only match an element in no namespace, it's very liberal about how the source tree gets constructed, and dropping namespaces during source construction, while against the spirit of the rules, is not actually non-conformant with any of the specs.